# How to properly make getComponentAfter set focus on jDateChooser

Tags: java, swing, focus

So I'm trying to implement the following:

```
public Component getComponentAfter(Container focusCycleRoot,
                     Component aComponent)
{
int idx = (order.indexOf(aComponent) + 1) % order.size();

return order.get(idx);
}
```

where order is a list of my elements. By doing this, the focus is going vertically BUT when it reaches `jDateChooser` it does't get any focus.

What do I need to set?

Comment: no idea for posted description, is possible to add, put JComponents (its custom derivates) to array and then moving Focus programatically, ZOrder will help you as simplest of possible ways, voting to close...

Comment: I did put my components to array, thats not the issue, and im moving tru them but when time comes to focus jDateChooser element it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it, problem was in jDateChooser as a Component so I set the following

```
 IDateEditor editor = jDateChooser9.getDateEditor();
    JComponent comp = editor.getUiComponent();
```

and then add comp to array.